# Tuples as dict keys where order may not always matter

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, graph-theory

I have a dictionary that uses tuples as keys.  The keys refer to edges between two nodes on a graph eg. "`vendor` connects to `account`" and the associated value is the strength of the connection so `('vendor','account'): 7`.  I need to be able to get the values from the dictionary in two ways: a) by passing in the key where the order of elements in the tuple is important b) where the order of the tuple is *not* important.  The difference is that sometimes the direction of the connection matters and sometimes it doesn't.  (In graph terms sometimes I consider the graph directed and sometimes undirected.)  Note that there are no duplicate tuple pairs eg. `(vendor,account) - (account,vendor)` so that makes things easier.

I came up with a way of accepting a tuple and matching it to the correct key regardless of order.  Unfortunately it means looping through all the keys every time.  I'm just wondering if there is a better way?

```
v_dict = {('vendor', 'account'):1,
        ('vendor', 'cost_center'):2,
        ('vendor', 'purchase_order'):3,
        ('vendor', 'user_name'):5,
        ('vendor', 'invoice'):6}

pair = [('purchase_order', 'vendor'), ('invoice','vendor'), ('vendor', 'user_name')]

key = []

[key.append(j) for j in v_dict.keys() for i in pair if i[0] in j and i[1] in j]

for key in key:
    print(key, v_dict[key])
```

Note:  I'm aware of and work with dedicated graph libraries.  In this instance I have to use just python.

Comment: Use a frozenset instead of a tuple? `{frozenset((1, 2, 3)): "foo"}[frozenset((3, 1, 2))] == "foo"`

Comment: Unrelated to your question: you shouldn't use a list comprehension for [side effects.](/q/5753597/843953)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two approaches:

1. Sort the tuple before attempting to use it as an index. That way, the order you get the tuple in doesn't matter.

   ```
   v_dict = {('vendor', 'account'):1,
           ('vendor', 'cost_center'):2,
           ('vendor', 'purchase_order'):3,
           ('vendor', 'user_name'):5,
           ('vendor', 'invoice'):6}

   v_dict = {tuple(sorted(k)): v for k, v in v_dict.items()}

   def get_vdict_value(key):
       return v_dict.get(tuple(sorted(key)))
   ```
2. Use a `frozenset` of your tuple as your key.

   ```
   v_dict = {frozenset(k): v for k, v in v_dict.items()}

   def get_vdict_value(key):
       return v_dict.get(frozenset(key))
   ```

Use the function we just defined to fix the key before getting it from the dict.

```
pairs = [('purchase_order', 'vendor'), ('invoice','vendor'), ('vendor', 'user_name')]

for pair in pairs:
    print(pair, get_vdict_value(pair))

# ('purchase_order', 'vendor') 3
# ('invoice', 'vendor') 6
# ('vendor', 'user_name') 5
```